# show div only when select value from dropdown is right

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show div only when "other" option selected from dropdown..otherwise it always display none...i try javascript but it shows all time any of option selected..

```html
<form>   
    <span style="font: 13px/19px Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Category</span><br>

    <select name="category" id="category" onchange="showHide();">
        
        <option value="0">----Select Category----</option>
        <option value="Accountants">Accountants</option>
        <option value="Solicitors">Solicitors</option>
        <option value="Bankers">Bankers</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHide() 
        {
            document.getElementById("foo").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
   
    <div id="foo" style="display:none;">
        <span style="font: 13px/19px Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Other Category</span><br>
        <input type="" name="other" placeholder="other" style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 7px; margin-bottom: 10px; font: 13px/19px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; "><br>
    </div>
 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; " class="btn" >
</form>
```

plz help....thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a "please fix this code" or "please modify this code to do XYZ" question...

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```html
<form>   
 <span style="font: 13px/19px Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Category</span><br>

 <select name="category" id="category" onchange="showHide(this);">
        
        <option value="0">----Select Category----</option>
        <option value="Accountants">Accountants</option>
        <option value="Solicitors">Solicitors</option>
        <option value="Bankers">Bankers</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(that) {
         if(that.value == "Others") {
            document.getElementById("foo").style.display = "block";
         } else {
            document.getElementById("foo").style.display = "none";
         }
    }
</script>
   
 <div id="foo" style="display:none;">
 <span style="font: 13px/19px Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Other Category</span><br>
 <input type="" name="other" placeholder="other" style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 7px; margin-bottom: 10px; font: 13px/19px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; "><br>
</div>
 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; " class="btn" >
</form>
```

**Explanation:**  What I have done:

I have added the condition in javascript function:

```
if(that.value == "Others")
```

If selected options value is Others then the div will appear.

I have passed the dropdown object in the function by using `this`. And using this object I can get the value of selected option. After that I have make a check in if condition.

Comment: dear,you are right.but once i select others then i wish to change option then below division cannt hide....so its not right.plz help

Comment: you can write the else part as document.getElementById("foo").style.display = "none";

Comment: @KetanJoshi I have modified with else part please check that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your onchange function to just check whether the selected value is Others before it changes the other controls style to block

```
function showHide() {
    var e = document.getElementById("category");
    if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value = "Others") {
        document.getElementById("foo").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of your **select** element inside the "showHide" function. Your "showHide" function will currently always display the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can set condition for the same:

```
function showHide(elem) { // this reference passed from markup
    if (elem.value.toLowerCase().trim() === "others") { // check for 'others'
        document.getElementById("foo").style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("foo").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

You need to pass `this` as a reference to your function `showHide(this)`

```
<select name="category" id="category" onchange="showHide(this);"></select>
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zapccLL/)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a code that worked fine for me.

```
<form>   
  <span style="font: 13px/19px Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Category</span><br>
  <select name="category" id="category" onchange="showHide(this);">

    <option value="0">----Select Category----</option>
    <option value="Accountants">Accountants</option>
    <option value="Solicitors">Solicitors</option>
    <option value="Bankers">Bankers</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
  </select>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(that) 
    {
         if(that.value == "Others")
         var other = document.getElementById("otr");
         other.style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

  <div id="otr" style="display:none;">
    <span style="font: 13px/19px Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Other Category</span><br>
    <input type="" name="other" placeholder="other" style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 7px; margin-bottom: 10px; font: 13px/19px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; "><br>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; " class="btn" >
</form>
```